# colortbl bug? Disappearing "," in colored row

Tags: color, colortbl

I encounter a strange problem with `colortbl`. This is my LaTeX input:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color, colortbl}

\begin{document}

%---

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}

\begin{tabular}{r@{, }l }\hline
     december 10 & 2011 \\\rowcolor{Gray}
        april 06 & 2012 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The problem occurs on the second row, between the first and the second column. There the "," is gone for some reason. The second row is a colored row, while the first row isn't. The problem doesn't occur on the first row. There the "," is typed out: the content is displayed correctly.

Comment: `\rowcolor` disregards the `@{,}` and has a wrong overhang in this case

Comment: Can this be considered as a bug?

Comment: No, it's by design ;-)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a by-pass-solution: Define the columns to be gray, regarding the `@{, }` and using explicit white and gray background colours for certain rows.

With `\rowcolors` it's possible to let the alternation occur automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}


\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}



\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{Gray}[\tabcolsep][\tabcolsep]}r@{, }>{\columncolor{Gray}[\arrayrulewidth][\tabcolsep]}l}\hline
  \rowcolor{white}december 10 &  2011 \\
  \rowcolor{Gray} april 06 & 2012 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\rowcolors{1}{white}{Gray}
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{Gray}[\tabcolsep][\tabcolsep]}r@{, }>{\columncolor{Gray}[\arrayrulewidth][\tabcolsep]}l}\hline
december 10 &  2011 \\
april 06 & 2012 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But what means < and > in the tabular specification? I don't find this in my LaTeX books.

Comment: @FranckyLeyn: You could ask Guho the same question ;-) `>` etc. is an addition by the `array` package, which is loaded by `colortbl` (or `xcolor` loading `colortbl` as well). You should look into the documentation of `array` (package, not the `array` environment)

Comment: r<{\hspace{-12pt}, }}l

Comment: @FranckyLeyn: Yes? What should I do with this?

Comment: In the table there are many columns. So the place where \tabcolsep should be zero is the exception to the rule. Therefore, I don't set \tabcolseb to zero, but insert a negative \hspace a the specific column. The specification of the columns then becomes: r<{\hspace{-12pt}, }}l For some reason, this doesn't work. Why?

Comment: @FranckyLeyn: That's another question and actually code from another solution not provided by me.

Comment: It's something provided by myself. But unfortionatly, I'm not such a big LaTeX expert, and so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`\rowcolor` colors each cell in the row individually and determines the size using the value of `\tabcolsep`. Your inclusion of a comma and space by `@{, }` reduces the separation between the two columns from the value given by `\tabcolsep`; as such, what you are seeing is the gray background from the year cell covering up the comma. This is apparent when the space after the comma is removed (i.e., `@{,}` is used):

[image: result w/o space]

A workaround: set `\tabcolsep` to `0pt` and use `<{, }` in place of `@{, }`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{r<{, }l}\hline
     december 10 & 2011 \\\rowcolor{Gray}
        april 06 & 2012 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Alternative: If you want look of the default `\tabcolsep` (which is `6pt`) and you don't want to color the columns and alternative rows as in [Christian Hupfer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283861/89497), you can append the requisite space to the first and last columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{\hspace{6pt}}r<{, }l<{\hspace{6pt}}}\hline
     december 10 & 2011 \\\rowcolor{Gray}
        april 06 & 2012 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: result with overhang]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected output (because, with `nicematrix`, the colored panels are added before the construction of the main array by using PGF/Tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix,color}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}

\begin{NiceTabular}[colortbl-like]{r@{, }l }\hline
     december 10 & 2011 \\\rowcolor{Gray}
        april 06 & 2012 \\
  \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]